# Combination/Distribution "n" different object "r" indentical boxes

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose i have 5 different balls, that are distributed into 4 identical boxes. How to do them?
Also, what is the exact formula or logic that i need to apply in this case?

Answer (score 2):

4 *identical* boxes can be assigned to 5 *different* balls $70$ ways.

This is solved using "[Stars and Bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two)".

It is essentially the same problem as counting ways to distribute 4 *identical* stars into five *different* bins, with the partitions between the bins represented by four bars.

The string '$\star\star\star\,\star\mid\;\mid\;\mid\;\mid$' has ${8 \choose  4}$ permutations.

$$\binom{8}{4}=\frac{8!}{4!\;4!} = \frac{8\times 7\times 6\times 5}{4\times 3\times 2\times 1} = 70$$

---

So in the case of $r$ *identical* boxes and $n$ *different* objects: $$\dbinom{r+n-1}{r}=\dbinom{r+n-1}{n-1}=\dfrac{(r+n-1)!}{r!(n-1)!}$$

Comment: Well ..this looks incorrect as you have counted few scenarios as double. This formula does not work.
http://www.veritasprep.com/blog/2011/12/quarter-wit-quarter-wisdom-unfair-distributions-in-combinatorics-part-ii/
See Question 3 on that page...the 4 identical in 5 different shows as 51 not 70.